# Java migration JDK 11 to JDK 17 fail Junit Test with Jakarta Marshal

Tags: java, character-encoding, jaxb, marshalling, jakarta-migration

I have an application on JDK11 with Spring Boot 2.7.11 and a Junit Test that use jaxb javax.xml.bind.Marshaller. All is OK

But I have to migrate to JDK17 with Spring Boot 2.7.18. So I have replace all my import of javax.xml.bind by jakarta.xml.bind.

After that, my Junit Test is failed becaus marshal produce XML object with wrong encoding char

```
 try {
      final JAXBContext jaxbContext = getJaxbContext(classes);
      marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
      marshaller.marshal(object, bos);
    } catch (final JAXBException ex) {
      throw new HttpMessageConversionException(
          "Could not create Marshaller for class [" + classes + "]: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
```

On marshaller.marshal(object, bos);, object contain all correct charecter but after marshaller, charter ar not ok

> Before Marshal : lorsDe=Retour à la maison

> After Marsha in XML : <LORS_DE>Retour Ã  la maison</LORS_DE>

I don't understand where is the problem. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with JDK17.

The default file encoding was UTF8 before JDK17, now it’s not UTF8 anymore.

You have to set it explicitly to UTF8 with:

‘java -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 myapp.jar”

You have to set this in your Dockerfile and also for your unit tests via the Maven surefire plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting SpringBoot 2.7.18 (even with JDK17), you should stick to `javax` imports.

`jakarta` support was introduced in SpringBoot 3.x as part of the Spring 6 plan to move to JakartaEE9 and JDK17 baseline

See [this post](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6) from Spring blog for reference

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're facing an issue with character encoding after migrating from javax.xml.bind to jakarta.xml.bind. In newer versions, there might be changes in default settings that affect the encoding behavior.

Try setting the encoding explicitly in your Marshaller:

```
try {
     final JAXBContext jaxbContext = getJaxbContext(classes);
      marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

      // Set encoding explicitly
     marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

     marshaller.marshal(object, bos);
} catch (final JAXBException ex) {
     throw new HttpMessageConversionException(
        "Could not create Marshaller for class [" + classes + "]: " + 
     ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

Make sure to replace "UTF-8" with the appropriate encoding you are using in your application.

Additionally, check if there are any other properties that need to be set for compatibility with the new version. You can refer to the documentation or release notes of the Jakarta XML Binding (JAXB) implementation you are using for any additional configuration changes.

Comment: Thanks; I have already add      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); without success. I check jakarta documentation but I found nothing

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073

Answer (score 0):

I found it !

MArshaller work well, but just after, xml is return with bos.toString. I have to indicate it that it's UTF8

```
return bos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```